OptaPlanner Task assigning score corruption
I have a Task which has two planning variables: Resource and startDateTime. EndDateTime is a shadow variable. Resource has a list of tasks via @InverseRelationShadowVariable, which I use to get the previous and next task. Each task has its travel time, which is the time from the previous task's location to that Task's location.
There are also some pinned tasks, such as pauses or private absences, which are scheduled in advance and should not be moved by OptaPlanner. These are essentially non-availabilities and do not have a location. For instance, in a scenario where a resource has assigned tasks A -> Pause -> B, the travel time for task B depends on task A, because it is the first previous task that is not a non-availability.
I have one hard constraint which ensures that tasks assigned to a resource do not overlap, including their travel time:
return constraintFactory.forEachIncludingNullVars(OPTask.class)
    .join(
        OPResource.class,
        Joiners.equal(OPTask::getResourceId, OPResource::getId))
    .filter((task, resource) -> task.isNewTask())
    .penalizeConfigurable((task, resource) -> {
      var command = OPConstraintProviderHelper.createCheckPolicyCommand(task, resource);
      return resourceAvailabilityRule.isViolated(command) ? 1 : 0;
    })
    .asConstraint(RESOURCE_AVAILABILITY);

This constraint fails with both FAST and FULL assert modes. I believe the issue arises when task A (from the example above) is replaced with, for example, task D, which then potentially causes an overlap of Pause and task B. OptaPlanner does not correctly account for how the score for B and its resource now results in a -1 hard score when B is not changed, even though we expect that the Resource has changed and that this pair should be included in the incremental score.
How should this be handled and is there a way to make the score for each task be affected by both that task and all other tasks assigned to the same resource?

Note: OptaPlanner hasn't released a new version in nearly a year. Timefold Solver is an actively maintained fork of OptaPlanner, which fixes a lot of bugs and introduces new features as well. You may find your problem already addressed in Timefold Solver. Or maybe not.

@LukášPetrovický I've migrated to Timefold and still getting excess constraint matches. I've also overriden equals and hashCode for object I'm constructing from joined pair of Task and Resource. Thing is, that list of all tasks assigned to resource is important to me and when any of them changes, score for all other tasks for that resource must be recalculated.
